# Filters in MOODLE

Tags: moodle

Edited Mycode by adding select element

If I want to add select element(say..list of courses) along with username element. I addded this way...but it was not working

```
 $params = array();
    if (!empty($usernamefilter) && !empty($coursesfilter)) 
    {
        $params['id'] = $usernamefilter;
        $params['courses'] = $coursesfilter;

        $sql .= ' AND '.$DB->sql_like('cc.id', ':id', false). ' AND '.$DB->sql_like('c.courses', ':courses', false).

}
```

Comment: Can you show the how you retrieve the data? Do you use any of the $DB functions in your custom page?

Comment: @Russell England : Here is my custom code page

Comment: @Russell England:: Could you guide me on how to add filters to a custom page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a form so the user can enter a username to search for - create a file called filter_form.php with this

```
defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die;

require_once($CFG->libdir . '/formslib.php');

class filter_form extends moodleform {

    public function definition() {
        $mform =& $this->_form;

        $mform->addElement('text', 'username', get_string('username', 'yourpluginname'));
        $mform->setType('username', PARAM_TEXT);

        $this->add_action_buttons(false, get_string('submit'));
    }

}
```

Then in your custom page have this to display or get the form

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/filter_form.php');
...
$mform = new filter_form();
$usernamefilter = '';
if ($formdata = $mform->get_data()) {
    $usernamefilter = $formdata->username;
}
$mform->display();
```

Then use this to search for the data - sql_like functions provide cross database compatibility - https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Data_manipulation_API#SQL_compatibility_functions

```
$sql = "SELECT u.username, u.firstname, gg.finalgrade
        FROM {grade_grades} gg
        JOIN {user} ON gg.userid = u.id
        WHERE gg.finalgrade IS NOT NULL";

$params = array();
if (!empty($usernamefilter)) {
    $params['username'] = '%' . $DB->sql_like_escape($usernamefilter) . '%';
    $sql .= " AND " . $DB->sql_like('u.username', ':username', false);
}

$mods = $DB->get_recordset_sql($sql, $params));
if ($mods->is_valid()) {
   // Display table
   ...
}
$mods->close();
```

If you are using get_recordset_sql then you need to use $mods->valid() and $mods->close() - https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Data_manipulation_API#Using_Recordsets

Comment: Excellent.. Russel England Thank You very much... it helped me alot and I learned on how to add filter searching.Many Thanks

Comment: If suppose if I have another select element(say..list of courses) along with text element in my form..then how could we extend our query like in the last edited code "If more than one filter"

Comment: :: Could you please suggest me on adding one more select filter